# Trigger a Jenkins Job when new code is pushed to BitBucket?

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I intend to trigger a Jenkins jobs (Hosted in the AWS cloud) when new code is pushed to the BitBucket Repo.

Currently I have setup Git which points to my Automation Test Framework:
[image]

I then have enabled the option (Addon): Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket as shown below:
[image]

Finally I have added the webhook URL within BitBucket using the following format:
http://PublicIpAddressOfAwsInstance:80/bitbucket-hook/
[image]

When I push new code to BitBucket it doesnt seem to automatically trigger a Jenkins job any ideas (Please note if I make a change to the AutomationFramework hosted on GitHub a Jenkins job gets triggered)?

thanks

Comment: What appears on the "view requests" link in Bitbucket?

Comment: thanks for the comment @Jim Redmond looks like im getting a 503 error.

Comment: Looks like adding security rules into within AWS is now showing a 200, will need to investigate what specific IP's etc need to be added.